# How to call a variable from a class without calling the class - c#?

Tags: c#, class

I want to use a const variable from this class:

```
 class foo
 {
    public const bool x = true;
 }
```

is there any way to use x without doing foo.x?

i want to use it like this:

```
if( x )
```

and not like this:

```
if( foo.x )
```

Comment: Not unless you are within the `foo` class. What's the problem with `foo.x`?

Comment: `foo.x` won't work either, unless you mark `x` as public.

Comment: Glorin is right. you cant in anyway call it as x.Since its defined within a class

Comment: Maybe you just want to declare x as a global variable of your application. It should not be a member of foo, or else it needs to define its class to get its value

Comment: @cnom there is no such thing as global variables in C#.  Everything has to be declared within a class or struct context.

Comment: VB.NET allows this with static classes (called "Modules").  Take *that* VB haters...

Comment: If someone can use x without creating a foo, then x is decoupled from foo. So, why put it inside foo?

Comment: @DavidL, correct, I meant "blobal" as if "in a higher level of scope", e.g. in a parrent class

Comment: forgot to add the public, the meaning of the question dosnt change though, public wont make you access it without accessing the class first...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only way to achieve that is to mark `foo` as static and use [`using static`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) where you want to have access to `foo.x` as `x`.

```
namespace Foo
{
    static class Bar
    {
         public const bool x = true;
    }
}
```

and later:

```
using static Foo.Bar;
Console.WriteLine(x);
```

`using static` is a C# feature, so make sure you're using C# 6 before you use it.

Comment: Still you are using the class reference, but you are hiding it through a `using`. Smart though...

Comment: @PatrickHofman Yep. But it's the same with regular `using` - you're actually using fully qualified name with namespace, but hiding it behind a `using`.

Comment: Yeah, true. Just wanted to point out this in fact makes no different.

Comment: So clever, so much potential for abuse and unclear code :).  But good alternative.

Comment: @DavidL I think it's primary meant to be used to bring into scope extension methods defined in a given static class (instead of all of them from a given namespace). But you can actually bring anything :)

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I agree, that is probably the original intention and it makes a lot of sense for that case so that you aren't exposing everything.  Clever and tricky the other things it allows however :P.

Comment: @TheNormalPotato If you think an answer solved your problem you should mark it as accepted. That's how StackOverflow works. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer for details.

Answer (score 2):

No, a member always stays a member of a class, so you either have to call a static (or constant) variable through the class name, or call the member on the instance.

So this would work:

```
public class Foo { public static int SomeInt {get;set;} = 12; }

int i = Foo.SomeInt;
```

Or:

```
public class Foo { public int SomeInt {get;set;} = 12; }

Foo f = new Foo();
int i = foo.SomeInt;
```

And as shown by Marcin, you can somewhat hide that truth by using `using static`. Still, it is called through the class.

Answer (score 0):

For starters it will need to be publicly accessible

```
public class foo
{
    public const bool x = true;
}
```

And then you can store the value in a variable

```
var x = foo.x;
if(x) { .. }
```